# Change ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton style dark/light mode is turned on

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, ios-darkmode

I have a sign in apple button. It has style `.black` in light mode:

```
let button = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .signIn, style: .black)
```

I want it to have style `.white` in dark mode

Accessing the style to change it does not seem possible like this:

```
button.style = .white
```

Does someone know if this is possible in a clean way? Without having to recreate a button when the

```
traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
```

detects a mode change?

Comment: It seems that you would need to create a new instance of the button.  Depending on your UI, the white outline style may work in both light and dark

Answer (score 2):

As far as I have found out, it is not possible to change the `style` of a `ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton` once it has been instantiated. The final solution has been instantiating two buttons on initialisation and only showing the needed one according to the current `traitCollection`. There are other solutions, but this one makes sure only two instances are needed altogether.

The two buttons are saved inside a stack view:

```
let blackButton = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .signIn, style: .black)
let whiteButton = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .signIn, style: .black)

private lazy var stackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [blackButton, whiteButton])
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    return stackView
}()
```

One can position the `stackView` there where one would position the regular button in the UI.

One would listen to trait collection changes and hide/show the desired button:

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
        let currentInterface = UITraitCollection.current
        // Only do a change when the style interface really changed
        guard previousTraitCollection?.userInterfaceStyle != currentInterface.userInterfaceStyle else {
            return
        }

        // Hide or show buttons depending on your design.
        if currentInterface.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
            blackButton.isHidden = true
            whiteButton.isHidden = false
        } else {
            blackButton.isHidden = false
            whiteButton.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```